# MVC.net form post/anti forgery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When defining the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute. What level of complexity should be given to the salt?

For example is an alpha-numeric over X number of characters characters good? Should there be symbols as well.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "How complex is good")]
public virtual ActionResult SaveDetail(UserDetails details)
{
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a matter of salt length rather than character types. Simply put, the longer the salt, the harder the AntiForgeryToken will be to crack. Modern methods such as md5-crypt and bcrypt use salts of 48 and 128 bits, respectively. Perhaps you want to follow their lead.

If you're really concerned, add a different salt to each view. This will provide added security to your site as hackers won't be able reuse a compromised token from view to view. Hopefully that makes sense.

Sanderson speak to this in [this post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/).

Answer (score 2):

i've added my 'salt' into a config file and use a guid for it's value (along the lines of):

```
public const string AntiforgeryToken = "{F161FDA9-D1F0-43D2-85D0-F7051F12E7B8}";
```

i reference it in the controllers like so:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = Config.AntiforgeryToken)]
```

seems to work quite well for me.

jim